# Android framework drawables

Tags: android, version-control, android-source

I need some files from Android framework (ICS) source for customizing my application. I found it here : https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr1-release/core/res/res/ but the size of whole repo is over 500MB. Since I have a slow connection I'm unable to download. Is there any way I can download only the content of https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr1-release/core/res/res/. Is this hosted somewhere else? Or is an SVN repo available?

Comment: You won't be able to do this from github-- github is all or nothing.  There is no way to target subfolders.  As for SVN that would work, but I don't know of Android being hosted on a public SVN repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know but maybe [this](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) webpage can help you.

Comment: Good find, but what I need is ICS drawables